# How to fetch groupmembership attribute from Oracle LDAP server(OID) using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, ldap, oid

I am using a VBScript to do an authentication between my application with OID(Oracle Identity Directory) using an LDAP script. I am successfull in doing authentication. The next step involved is fetching all the groups that user is belonging to and map with the groups in my application. For some reasons I am not able to fetch the group information from the LDAP server. I know the attribute I should query is "groupmembership". But I am not able to get any values from this attribute. Any help on this is required. Here is a code snippet of what I have -

```
'ldapauth.vbs
'Version: 1.0
'Use:  c:\cscript ldapauth.vbs <userName> [<password>]
'Ex - Anonymous:       c:\>cscript ldapauth.vbs svc_testconsona
'Ex - Authenticated:   c:\>cscript ldapauth.vbs svc_testconsona wipro@123

Dim oUser      'LDAP object holding user info
Dim oDSP       'Directory Service Provider
Dim oArgs      'Command line arguments
Dim sCN        'search parameter - LDAP attribute: CN
Dim sPWD       'CN's password parameter
Dim sRoot      'Holds the root of the LDAP object
Dim sDN        'Distinguished Name of authenticating account
Dim sLDAPsrv   'LDAP server
Dim sLDAPsb    'LDAP search base
Dim bAuthQuery 'Query Type - True=Authenticated, False=Anonymous

CONST ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = &H0001
CONST ADS_USE_ENCRYPTION = &H0002
CONST ADS_USE_SSL = &H0002
CONST ADS_READONLY_SERVER = &H0004
CONST ADS_NO_AUTHENTICATION = &H0010
CONST ADS_FAST_BIND = &H0020
CONST ADS_USE_SIGNING = &H0040
CONST ADS_USE_SEALING = &H0080
CONST ADS_USE_DELEGATION = &H0100
CONST ADS_SERVER_BIND = &H0200
Const ADS_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND  = &h8000500D

sLDAPsrv = "myserver.domain.com:389"
sLDAPsb = "ou=Active,o=CMI"

'Get the command line args
set oArgs=WScript.Arguments

'Check command line args
On Error Resume Next
sCN = oArgs.item(0)    'username
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Echo ""
    Echo "**** ERROR: No username supplied."
    Echo ""
    Echo "Use: c:\>cscript ldapauth.vbs <userName> [<password>]"
    Echo ""
    Echo "Aborting..."
    Echo ""
    WScript.Quit
End If

sRoot = "LDAP://" & sLDAPsrv & "/cn=" & sCN & "," & sLDAPsb
sDN = "cn=" & sCN & "," & sLDAPsb

wscript.echo "the query is:"
wscript.echo sRoot

On Error Resume Next
sPWD = oArgs.item(1)   'password
If Err.Number <> 0 Then   'This will be a non-authenticated query
    bAuthQuery = False
    Echo ""
    Echo "Performing anonymous LDAP query..."
    Echo ""
Else    'This will be an authenticated query
    bAuthQuery = True
    Echo ""
    Echo "Performing authenticated LDAP query..."
    Echo ""
End If
'Done checking command line args

'Set directory service provider
Set oDSP = GetObject("LDAP:")

'Perform requested type of query - anonymous or authenticated
If bAuthQuery Then   'authenticated query requested

    'Set the LDAP object query
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oUser = oDSP.OpenDSObject(sRoot,sDN,sPWD,ADS_SERVER_BIND)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        If Err.Number = "-2147023570" Then
            Echo "**** ERROR: Authentication failed. Check username, password and search base."  
        ElseIf Err.Number = "-2147016646" Then
            Echo "**** ERROR: LDAP server not found."  
        Else 
            Echo "**** ERROR: Unable to bind to LDAP server. " & Err.Number
        End If
        Echo ""
        Echo "Use: c:\>cscript ldapauth.vbs <username> <password>"
        Echo ""
        Echo "Aborting..."
        Echo ""
        WScript.Quit
    End If

Else                 'anonymous query requested

    'Set the LDAP object query
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oUser = oDSP.OpenDSObject(sRoot,vbNullString,vbNullString,ADS_SERVER_BIND AND ADS_NO_AUTHENTICATION)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        If Err.Number = "-2147016656" Then
            Echo "**** ERROR: Username not found."
        ElseIf Err.Number = "-2147016646" Then
            Echo "**** ERROR: LDAP server not found."  
        Else 
            Echo "**** ERROR: Unable to bind to LDAP server. " & Err.Number
        End If
        Echo ""
        Echo "Use: c:\>cscript ldapauth.vbs <username [<password>]"
        Echo ""
        Echo "Aborting..."
        Echo ""
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End If

'Populate the user property cache
oUser.GetInfo



'Iterate through available user attributes
For count = 0 to (oUser.PropertyCount-1)
    sAttribName = oUser.Item(CInt(count)).Name
    -'This line fetches the attribute name poroperly. But values from groupmembership is not getting it.
    if sAttribName = "groupmembership" then
        sAttribVal = oUser.GetInfoEx(sAttribName)
    else
        sAttribVal = oUser.Get(sAttribName)
    end if

    If IsArray(sAttribVal) Then
        For Each sMultiVal in oUser.GetEx(sAttribName)
            sAttribList = sAttribList & sAttribName & Space(16-Len(sAttribName)) & ":: " & sMultiVal & vbCRLF
        Next
    Else
        sAttribList = sAttribList & sAttribName & Space(16-Len(sAttribName)) & ":  " & sAttribVal & vbCRLF
    End If
    sAttribName = ""
    sAttribVal = ""
    if err.number <> 0 then
        err.Clear
    end if
Next

Echo sAttribList



'Clean up
set oDSP=Nothing
set oUser=Nothing

wscript.Quit

Sub Echo(byref message)
   WScript.Echo message
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

OID doesn't normally have an attribute on a user called `groupmembership` (unless you added one yourself).

If you are trying to find the groups that a user is a member of, you have to do a second ldap search for the groups.

Groups in OID have either `groupOfNames` or `groupOfUniqueNames` as their object class. Each of these object classes has a multivalued attribute for storing the names of group members. When a user is assigned to a group, their DN is added to the respective multivalued attribute. In the `groupOfNames` object class, this multivalued attribute is member, and, in the `groupOfUniqueNames` object class, it is `uniqueMember`.

Comment: Finally I have solved my problem. In all the means VBScript is not enumerating the groupmembership attribute. I Switched my implementation by writing a ASP.NET web service call which internally uses Directory services LDAP namespace. Using this I am able to fetch all the attributes and enumerate all the groups as well. Thanks Srinath